# How to deal with differently translated prepositions?

Tags: translation, language

I'm maintaining a Wordpress site in both English and Portuguese. I'm using .po and .mo files.

The site is related to elections.

In English, you can always say "Candidates in {{state}}". In Portuguese, depending on the state, this can be "Candidatos no {{state}}" or "Candidatos em {{state}}". As far as I'm aware, this is just 'how it is'.

What's the best way to deal with this, such that these translations are correct, every time?

Comment: No answer then I think that a solution is to put in the PO file, the strings "no AAA", "em BBB"...

Comment: @Kaperto: Not ideal, as that requires the names of the states to be in the translation files. In this case, the number of states is limited, so this *would* be possible, but in another situation, it could be cities, or geographical structures, to which the same could apply.